# Extracting special content from a Onenote page to an excel sheet

Tags: xml, excel, onenote, vba

I please need some help regarding extraction of special infos of a OneNote 2010 page. My aim is to get the content of the tables in Onenote and put it into an excel sheet to get a quick and updated overview of different peoples' notes (by activating the macro).
In VBA i used nodes of 'IXMLDOMNodeList' to get its hierarchy:

```
Dim PageNodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim PageNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Set PageNodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//one:Page")
```

I than use a loop to get the content of every page

```
For Each PageNode In PageNodes
    ...    
    GetAttributeValueFromPageNode = PageNode.Attributes.getNamedItem("ID").Text
```

So far so good, but how can i limit the output of the content to a specific cell of a table?

The xml-block for one cell looks like:

```
<one:Cell lastModifiedTime="2015-05-12T14:46:23.000Z" objectID="{2C35AF52-393D-4E4E-8431-E7E189A2E6A1}{25}{B0}" lastModifiedByInitials="xxxxxx"><one:OEChildren><one:OE creationTime="2015-05-12T14:46:23.000Z" lastModifiedTime="2015-05-12T14:46:23.000Z" objectID="{2C35AF52-393D-4E4E-8431-E7E189A2E6A1}{26}{B0}" alignment="right" quickStyleIndex="1" style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:14.0pt;text-align:right"><one:T><![CDATA[Max Mustermann]]></one:T></one:OE></one:OEChildren></one:Cell>
```

The specific info in this case ("Max Mustermann") is embraced by CDATA[].

My ideas and trys have been:

- try to find and select "childnodes" of '//one:Page' (unfortunately page nodes have no childnodes)
- try to point to the 'object-ID' (but this changes everytime the onenote user creates a new site). I noticed that the last 2 brackets of the 'object-ID' remain constant.
- How can i parse this info out of the xml? (perhaps using wildcards for the object-iD?)

Every hint will be appreciated.
Thank you very much in advance, Ray

Comment: Ok, finally i found a solution by using the split function with the delimiter "{26}":
        Debug.Print Split(Split(Split(Split(CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject").opentextfile(path).readall, _
            "{26}{B0}")(1), "</one:Table")(0), "[CDATA[")(1), "]")(0)